# Access JavaScript variable from Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an HTML combobox which needs to be dynamically constructed upon page loading, and I need to do something like this:

```
<select id='sort-combobox'>
    <option value='1' {% if sesionStorage.getItem('sortFilter') == 1 %} selected {% endif %}>Newest</option>
    <option value='2' {% if sesionStorage.getItem('sortFilter') == 2 %} selected {% endif %}>>Price ASC</option>
    <option value='3' {% if sesionStorage.getItem('sortFilter') == 3 %} selected {% endif %}>Price DESC</option>
</select>
```

How can I access `sessionStorage.getItem('sortFilter')` from Django template?

`sortFilter` is stored whenever combobox value is changed. This is how it's done:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
    var combobox = document.getElementById('sort-combobox');
    combobox.addEventListener('change', comboboxContentChanged);

    function comboboxContentChanged() {
        mapping = {
            '1': 'products:products-list',
            '2': 'products:sort-results-price-asc',
            '3': 'products:sort-results-price-desc'
        }

        sessionStorage.setItem('sortFilter', combobox.value);
        window.location.replace(Urls[mapping[combobox.value]]());
    }
});
```

and this is my view:

```
def sort_results_price_desc(request):
    products_list = Product.objects.order_by('-price')
    paginator = Paginator(products_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    products = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'products/product_list.html', {'products': products})
```

Comment: You can use `request.session` in django to have ambiguous access to your vars.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis can you please tell me more?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Why would you want to do this in Django code at all? Since you're dynamically constructing this code in JS, why don't you set the `selected` attribute in that same JS?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm dynamically constructing the combobox in the Django template, not in JS. However I'm open to hearing your suggestion

Comment: Well you're going to need to show a bit more information. Exactly how are you storing that `sortFilter` data in the first place? How are you rendering this template? Show the relevant views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated my question, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I can't help feeling this whole approach is wrong. Why have separate views for each type of ordering? Why store the order in session storage rather than in the Django session? If you need parameters in your view you should be passing them there in by submitting a form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well, I'm still just learning. I'm not sure how would I handle filtering products with only one view. I feel the need for some kind of view parameters as you said. I'm not sure I need a form, are you suggesting a GET request? I only need a combobox and no additional submit button, that's why I use JavaScript to store sort filter.